# how to use application.conf file in maven pom.xml for flyway configuration

Tags: scala, maven, typesafe

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_abc</url>
        <user>db_user</user>
        <sqlMigrationPrefix>V</sqlMigrationPrefix>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't want to mention driver, url and user here. I already have a resources.conf on src/main/resources. How can use that file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
<artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<configuration>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_abc</url>
    <user>db_user</user>
    <sqlMigrationPrefix>V</sqlMigrationPrefix>
</configuration>
<configFiles>
    <configFile>myConfig.conf</configFile>
</configFiles>
</plugin>
```

Taken from Flyway Documentation: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate

myConfig.conf:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_abc
```

see documentation on flyway config files: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configfiles

Comment: I am looking to pass the `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_abc` from conf file.

Comment: see updated answer. hope it helps. but you should also read the documentation in order to understand your configuration